# Get only digits using regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I have in table column `pnum_s`

I need get only that rows, which value in column `pnum_s` is exactly 10 symbol and all these symbols are only digits

what query must write for this?

I am trying this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pnum_s REGEXP '^\d+$'
```

But this not returns 0 rows.

Comment: Do you need to escape `\d`?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not familiar with how MySQL does Regular Expressions but according to (http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html) backslashes need to be escaped.  OP issue may be you should use `\$` rather then just `$`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is either `'^[0-9]{10}$'` or `'^[[:digit:]]{10}$'`.

Everything is [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Can I use where column_name REGEXP '[0-9]' it is also working

Comment: @RandomSeed, Is there any way to restrict alphanumeric value

Answer (score 7):

I think with Mysql you'll want something like this:

```
^[[:digit:]]{10}$
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out the reference page.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

What you're looking for is this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pnum_s REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{10}$';
```

Answer (score 2):

try this pattern:

```
'^[0-9]{10}$'
```