# How to create unique slug?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a unique slug (while adding new data) and update slug (while updating existing data).

I want to have a mySQL query like:-

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cms WHERE (slug = '$slug' OR slug LIKE '$slug-{{numeric-value}}%'"
```

The idea is, `slug = '$slug'` will check whether an exact match exists and `slug LIKE '$slug-{{numeric-value}}%'` will check whether slugs like `about-us-2`, `about-us-3` exists. However, `about-us-more` will treated as be a different slug.

How can I create the accurate mySQL query?

Comment: you probably aren't using codeigniter, but still, this may be interesting to you: https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Slug-Library/blob/master/Slug.php

Comment: MySQL supports regular expressions (at least to find rows) which you could use to look for numeric values, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922248/get-only-digits-using-regexp) (and many similar ones), although you may also add a table that contains a list of slugs and its current number.