# MySQL 5.7 Compare only numbers from a mixed VARCHAR column

Tags: mysql, sql

> NOTE: Please note this is **NOT** the same as *similarly* titled questions (see "What I've Tried", below)

## Background:

I need to search a database string column for a phone number that matches a given search criteria.

The database column is a varchar with various user supplied additional (ie non-numeric) characters.

My original idea was to use a system to convert the column string to a numeric only format (in PHP this would be via PCRE functions) and then do a straight indentical comparison

## Example data held:

> ```
> id        telephone:
> ----------------------
>  1     '01576 456 567'
>  2     '07768345998'
>  3     '+447588 43 34 56'
>  4     '01524-901-335'
> ```

There are a variety of human readable formats held, these are submitted by the end user and are often historic.

## Problem:

I can not find a way to search this column for a number. I have stripped down the search field in PHP to number only (0-9). I want to try something like:

> "Search the telephone column and find where the numeric ONLY value (from a mixed string) matches the given search string exactly.
>
> *(pseudo-code:)*
>
> ```
>    SELECT telephone, id FROM phones WHERE 
>           REGEX_REPLACE(`telephone`, '[^0-9]') = :searchNumber
> ```

*(:searchNumber is the PDO placeholder.)*

## Example Search Term:

> "01576456567"

## Expected output:

From entering the search term into the SQL query I want to be able to retrieve the id number. In the above search example; `$result['id'] = 1;`

## Limitations:

This is on MySQL vesion 5.7 only. I can not use MySQL 8.0 here.

It would cause a lot of secondary work to convert the phone columns to numeric column types and we don't have the time flexibility to do this right now.

## What I've Tried:

- The [REGEXP type functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) on MYSQL return `true`/`false` (0/1) rather than a REGEXP processed output string.
- `CASE` to `SIGNED`/`UNSIGNED` does not work because it breaks at any whitespace in the string and also can lop off the leading zero.
- I have read [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510736/mysql-select-only-numeric-values-from-varchar-column) [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql) [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922248/get-only-digits-using-regexp)

## Escape Clause:

If my query is confusing this PHP code may better example what I'm trying to achieve.

- If all else fails I can export all of the numbers and run them through a PHP loop which would do the same thing:

  ```
  $searchNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$searchNumberSource);
  foreach ($numberFromDb as $row){
       if(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/',''.$row) === $searchNumberSource){
           // Matching number is found.
           break;
       }
  }
  ```

Comment: You gave us sample table data, but you did not show us what the search term is, nor what the expected output is.  Can you include this too?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah sorry,  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial way is a nested   use of replace

```
select replace(replace(replace(telephone,' ',''), '-',''), '+','')
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but my concern is that I need to manually list the non-numeric values appearing in the phone number VARCHAR. I was ideally hoping to find a way of sidestepping this potential block.

Comment: @Martin  .. i have tried  several time in past  .. and the end of my attempts .. the unique SQL based way was the use of replace.. anyway this could be at least a starting point..

Comment: My brain had got stuck on regex methods and I had overlooked `Replace`, but yes, testing this now it works... all I need now is to create a difinitive list of non numeric characters in the tabe column `:-D`. Thanks.

Comment: @martin  .. if my answer si right should be correct mark it properly

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data so it matches how you want to use it.  That may take some effort now, but fixing the data will simplify your code ongoing -- rather than having arduous work-arounds.

My suggestion is to make the change on the application side.  Change the number to a regular expression:

```
SELECT telephone, id
FROM phones
WHERE telephone REGEXP :searchNumber_regex;
```

Then `:searchNumber_regex` for `'"01576456567'` would look like:

```
'^[^0-9]*0[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*5[^0-9]*7[^0-9]*6[^0-9]*4[^0-9]*5[^0-9]*6[^0-9]*5[^0-9]*6[^0-9]*7[^0-9]*$'
```

Basically, the pattern `[^0-9]*` is at the beginning and end and in-between every number.

Comment: I had considered this approach (using the REGEXP comparison) but this seemed a very heavy and verbose work around, I'd rather export it all to PHP and use my PHP string processing method.

Comment: @Martin . . . It is probably less expensive to do the string processing in the database, especially if you have even a largish table.  Moving data from the database to the application is relatively expensive.